# Is there a way to use custom sql queries with various arguments in django?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, windows

I'm creating an application that allows a user to filter through millions of records in a database (using dates, post types, etc.). The problem is that the database queries I need to perform are kind of complicated to use Django's ORM so I need to use custom SQL, and I don't have much experience dealing with SQL and this part of Django.

If I needed the user specified filters before executing the query, how can I put in custom SQL without knowing how many filters/parameters there might be? And after that, how do I return what I found through that custom query into views so that the results can be displayed on the web page?

I've already looked at the Django documentation on raw and custom SQL queries but there isn't a lot of documentation and help on custom SQL queries outside of the Django official documentation, so any help would be appreciated.

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
      cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
      row = cursor.fetchone()

   return row
```

The example code here is from the documentation. Say the filter had other possible parameters in addition to WHERE baz = %s. If there was a possibility of having say date = %s and category = %s if the user selected it, would I need to write a conditional in python and create a new query for this? Or can i conditionally amend the query based on how many filter parameters the user wants?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use raw queries over the Django ORM?

Comment: the queries I need to run and the datasets I have are rather large so doing it that way takes a long time performance wise. i don't know how much faster doing it with raw sql is, which is why I want to test it out :)

Comment: If you use the ORM effectively, the difference in time, is insignificant, since constructing the query is usally very small compared to making the actual query.

Comment: I would rather build a `params` map conditionally and execute `cursor.execute(sql, [params])`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but as i understand it orms instatiate complete objects for each row and return them right? For large sets the penalty for doing all this accumulates, no?

Comment: @JakubP do you mean conditionally create a list of params based on what's needed and just pass that in?

Comment: yes, if You expose this query to user's and cannot predict which filters they will use, it would be better to build a `params` map

Comment: @JakubP Okay i get that i can build a params list and conditionally populate it, but how does this work within the SQL code if i am unsure of the number of arguements? for instance as an example, `SELECT * FROM joblist WHERE (job = 'office', OR job = 'teacher', OR job = 'student') AND date > '07-01-2019' AND date < '2019-07-15' ; ` I would need to fill each string with an `%s` correct? how do i fill this in the sql code if i don't know how many `%s` I need in the first place?